# Twitter bootstrap. Add a new class when class"affix" is added

Tags: jquery, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox, affix

I've a question regarding bootstrap affix and CSS3.

```
<section id="main">
   <div class="myContainer">
    some content
   </div>

   <aside class="cart-wrapper" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="50">
    some content
   </aside>
</section>
```

I'm using flexbox, so the div #main has

```
#main{
 display:flex;
 height: 100%;
 align-items: stretch;
}
```

and the aside .cart-wrapper has

```
.cart-wrapper{
width: 400px;
}
```

The cart-wrapper must be on the right side of the page. When users scroll down the page, after 50px, I want this div in fixed. So i'm using affix plugin of bootstrap. 
Everything works fine, but when bootstrap adds the .affix class to the cart-wrapper, the #main div grows, filling the page. This because the cart-wrapper, when the affix class is added, is out of the flow (position: fixed).

To avoid the growth of the #main div I want to add a class, like this one:

```
.affixAdded{margin-right: 400px;}
```

In this way, the layout is the same, even after that the .affix class is added.

I'm trying to do this with jquery. I've try this code, but it doesn't work.

```
if($('#cart-wrapper').hasClass('affix'){
  $('#main').addClass('affixAdded');
}
```

Could you help me to figure out why it doesn't work or how can reach my goal?
Thank you so much

Comment: You're missing a closing `)` in your `if` statement.

Comment: It's a typo. There is it in the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have not tested this code yet. But from what i understand, the problem is when scrolling. So check when the user scrolls, and if there is an element with class affix it will add the class to the #main element, else it would remove it.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($('some_element').length == 0) {
        $('#main').removeClass('affixAdded');
    }
    else{
        $('#main').addClass('affixAdded');
    }
});
```